# "TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" Error in nltk

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

```
news="U.S. President Donald Trump said on Tuesday he and Chinese President Xi Jinping will have a signing ceremony to sign the first phase of the U.S.-China trade deal agreed to this month."

news_token=word_tokenize(news) 

news_pos=nltk.pos_tag(news_token)

news_entity=ne_chunk(news_pos)

news_entity
```

Though I got the output,at the same tcl error occurring.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a question. Do not send screenshots. Send 1. Your code 2. Your Expected output 3. The Error in plaintext. Use markdown formatting

Comment: Also, do not share screenshots that give information that is not required to the question. Your screenshot tells you were browsing scihub which is illegal in several countries

Comment: Adding image and correcting some spelling  mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it worked fine for me...

[image]